# C# Navigate to a different Folder for startupPath

Tags: c#, wpf, path

I have an executable in the Solution of which I added, I want to replace the System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath to the executable location. Unfortunately it's continues to navigate to the Bin\debug folder which I don't want, I need to go up an additional level.

```
string pintoolpath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Replace(@"\bin\Debug", "").Replace(@"\bin\Release", "");
```

That's how I'm doing it but it's actually not replacing it at all when printing it to a message box. How would I navigate to say a another folder.

FYI: using the ..\ to navigate up does not currently work as shown below:

```
string pintoolpath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Replace(@"..\\bin\Debug", "").Replace(@"..\\bin\Release", "");
```

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath is byfault the executables path. For what you are trying to achieve, one way would be to keep the Startup path in a temporary string variable like 'string StartupPath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;'  and then replace its content to '
string pintoolpath = StartupPath.Replace("bin\\Debug", "bin\\Release")'

Comment: Interesting comment - but this is what I had to replace as example:    string pintoolpath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Replace(@"\bin\Debug", "").Replace(@"\bin\Release", "") + @"\Notepad\Notepad.exe";

But for some reason the folder structure doesn't actually navigate to the Notepad Folder and exe the Notepad (FYI using that as an example)

Comment: Why are you using startup path then. just give your own location like 'string pintoolpath = "D:\\AbcFolder\\XyzFolder\\Notepad\\Notepad.exe"' just mention your file/folder path using double backslash \\

Comment: Because I've added the executable in the Solution Explorer and anyone who downloads the tool needs access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out my answer,

The directly path on the Solution Explorer had characters that were different then the actual path. For example the B in Bin was capitalized in the actual path VS the solution explorer having it as a lower case. once changing these I was able to get the correct path by navigating to the appropriate folder.

```
string pintoolpath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Replace(@"\Bin\debug", "").Replace(@"\Bin\release", "")
```

Thanks Rahul for assisting me.

Comment: Though I didn't help u in any better way, but its good you figured it out all by yourself :)